# problema peticion get Status Code: 302 sitema MVC

Tags: javascript

Tengo un sistema desarrollado MVC con lengujes en javascrip y php y me está pasando algo extraño con las URLs. Resulta que cuando hago unas peticiones an un archivo para que me cargue los tipos de roles de usuario mediante ajax no me trae dichos roles y se me sale del sistema, investigando en el navegador doy cuenta que el archivo de tipo html generado me salta Status Code 302. Pongo los codigos para que vean si es algun problema en mi codigo.

Codigo con el cual cargo los roles:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    fntRolesUsuario();}, 
false);
function fntRolesUsuario(){
if(document.querySelector('#listRolid')){
    let ajaxUrl = BASE_URL+'/Roles/getSelectRoles';
    let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    request.open("GET",ajaxUrl,true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            document.querySelector('#listRolid').innerHTML = request.responseText;
            $('#listRolid').selectpicker('render');
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Codigo con el cual genero el archivo con los datos el cual llamo en la variable ajaxUrl del codigo de ariba

```
public function getSelectRoles()
    {
        $htmlOptions = "";
        $arrData = $this->model->selectRoles();
        if(count($arrData) > 0 ){
            for ($i=0; $i < count($arrData); $i++) { 
                if($arrData[$i]['status'] == 1 ){
                $htmlOptions .= '<option value="'.$arrData[$i]['idrol'].'">'.$arrData[$i]['nombrerol'].'</option>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo $htmlOptions;
        die();      
    }
```

El codigo de arriba genera bien la url y obtengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]